# In the regex world what's a flavor and which flavor does Java use?

Tags: java, regex

I'm not a native English and so I don't understand well the meaning of 'flavor'
may be is it referred to a regex syntax?? and if so how many regex syntax are there?

BRE ERE Perl etc.??

Comment: The API documentation of class `java.util.regex.Pattern` describes the exact syntax of regular expressions in Java.

Comment: For a more thorough comparison of regex flavors, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular-expression_engines

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The term "flavor" refers to the regex engine – the syntax and additional properties supported by the particular regex engine.

The `Pattern` class documents the properties of the [Java regex engine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).
Aside from the basic things like the meaning of metacharacters, different implementations of regex engines support different types of syntaxes.

For example:

- POSIX engines support `[:digit:]` for digits (same as `[0-9]`);
- Perl compatible engines support `\d` shortcut for digits;
- JavaScript doesn't support lookbehinds;
- PHP and some others support lookbehinds, but needs them to be fixed length;
- Regex engines of text editors (Notepad++) generally don't support lookarounds.

Answer (score 19):

There are many different variations of what features a regex engine implements, what technique it uses "under the hood" and what syntax it uses for certain features.

There is a very good article and comparison table at [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html).

The Java regex package implements a "Perl-like" regular expressions engine, but it has some extra features like possessive quantifiers (`.*+`) and variable-length (but finite) lookbehind assertions). On the other hand, it misses a few features Perl has, namely conditional expressions or comments. All in all, it's a very full-featured implementation.

Answer (score 4):

Java uses perl like reg-ex syntax

Answer (score 2):

A nice overview can be found here: [Comparison of Regular Expression Engines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines).

Answer (score 1):

A "flavor" in this context is a particular syntax, as you have surmised.  There are many; counting them would be only an academic endeavor.

To find the ones that are generally used, look at the forms accepted by `grep`.

Java may use whatever syntax has a Java implementation.