# Which regex standard does Java implement?

Tags: java, regex, standards

Which regular expression standard(s) (if any) are implemented by modern *Java* versions?

Is it [PCRE](http://pcre.org/), [GNU ERE](http://www.regular-expressions.info/gnu.html), [POSIX ERE](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html)?

Which standard should I refer to in the documentation, when giving a *Java* application with regex support to end users who are most probably not programmers nor are aware of *Java*? I feel providing a link to [`java.util.regex.Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum) API is not a good choice.

I'm not asking which RE **flavour(s)** Java supports (has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226325)) but rather which formal **standards** it adheres to.

Comment: I suggest having a look at [Comparison of regular expression engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines).

Comment: @stribizhev: thanks, looked at it already. It compares *engines* (i. e. *implementations*), and doesn't provide any engine-to-standard mapping.

Comment: The official documentation mentions Perl 5 standard only, see [*Comparison to Perl 5*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). Since it is a modification, there is no other way of referencing it as *Java's implementation of Perl 5 regex flavor*.