# What flavor of regex does git use

Tags: regex, git, git-diff

I'm trying to use the git diff --word-diff-regex= command and it seems to reject any types of lookaheads and lookbehinds. I'm having trouble pinning down what flavor of regex git uses. For example

```
git diff --word-diff-regex='([.\w]+)(?!>)'
```

Comes back as an invalid regular expression.

I am trying to get all the words that are not HTML tags. So the resulting matches of the regex should be 'Hello' 'World' 'Foo' 'Bar' for the below string

```
<p> Hello World </p><p> Foo Bar </p>
```

Comment: It seems that lookahead isn't supported.  Maybe you should let us know what the logic is in case there be a workaround not involving lookahead.

Comment: I updated my question to show what I need to regex for

Comment: It uses POSIX ERE. Or even BRE. POSIX has never supported lookarounds.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Git source uses `regcomp` and `regexec`, which are defined by POSIX 1003.2.  The [code to compile a diff regexp](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.39.0/diff.c#L2212) is:

```
            if (regcomp(ecbdata->diff_words->word_regex,
                        o->word_regex,
                        REG_EXTENDED | REG_NEWLINE))
```

which in POSIX means that these are "extended" regular expressions as defined [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html).

(Not every C library actually implements the same POSIX `REG_EXTENDED`.  Git includes its own implementation, which can be built in place of the system's.)

Edit (per updated question): POSIX EREs have neither lookahead nor lookbehind, nor do they have `\w` (but `[_[:alnum:]]` is probably close enough for most purposes).

Comment: No wonder. I was banging my head for why `\w+` won't work. Thanks for the hint of this answer, now `[[:alnum:]]+` seems to work. I still haven't made up my mind to learn and remember a new set of regex rules, though.

Comment: @RayLuo: there are too many to keep them all straight, but fortunately there are web sites for that. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3226325/1256452) and its links, including [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular-expression_engines). I think I like [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) more though.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the hints from @torek 's answer above, now I realize that there are [different flavors of regular expression engines](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular-expression_engines#Language_features) and they could even have different syntax.

Even for one particular program, such as git, it could be compiled with a different regex engine. For example, [this blog post](https://blog.ipspace.net/2020/04/git-tip-word-diff.html) hints that `\w` would be supported by git, contradicting with what I observed from my machine or what the OP here asked.

I ended up finding [this section from your recommended wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_classes) most helpful, in terms of presenting different syntax in one table, so that I could do some "translation" between for example `[:alnum:]` and `\w`, `[:digit:]` and `\d`, `[:space:]` and `\s`, etc..