# How to make a positive lookahead regex match when using Git's built-in regex matching?

Tags: regex, git

I can't make a positive lookahead based regex to work in `git grep` and/or `git log -L`. I'm using `git log -L <funcname>:<filename>` feature using a regex `<funcname>`. The test file is the following one :

```java
public class FakeFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println('Hello World');
    }
    public static void method2() {
        System.out.println('method2');
    }
    public static void method2(float i) {
        System.out.println(String.format('method2 %f', i));
    }
    public static void method3() {
        System.out.println('method3');
    }
}
```

and following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3533526/4075169), I'm using `^(?=.*float i).*method2.*$` to match the line where `method2` is defined with a float argument. It works on [rubular](https://rubular.com/r/Lgrkij44UDb34C), but I can't make it work in my shell using either `grep` or `git log -L`. I've tried to surround it with `'` and `\` characters, without success.

Any idea ?

EDIT : add a missing `.*` is the regex.

Comment: In the rubular demo you use `^(?=.*float i).*method2.*$` which is not the same as `^(?=float i).*method2.*$` Did you try `grep -oP` if that is supported?

Comment: Right, again, you can't expect arguments to be declared before the method name, so you still do not need a lookaround, `^.*method2.*float i.*` would do.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I need a way to match argument in any order, that's why I was considering positive lookahead. You're right, I've made a typo in the message, I'm changing it to include `.*` in the lookahead.

Comment: @Thefourthbird I can't rely on grep parameters since I need the regex to work with `git log -L` command, but thanks for the comment !

Comment: At any rate, POSIX regex does not support lookarounds. You can't use them here. If you can use `-P` to enable PCRE engine, only then you can use lookarounds.

Comment: @Thefourthbird, I'll definitely try to used the alternation version of the regex, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As [Wiktor Stribiżew notes in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69705205/how-to-make-a-positive-lookahead-regex-match-when-using-gits-built-in-regex-mat/69712398#comment123209530_69705205), you can use `^float i.*method2.*` here to match the lines (though as "function names" this might be more than you want—but at least in the `git log -L` output, these are just text anyway).

Ultimately, the issue here has to do with which regular expression syntax(es) Git supports.

The primary ones, generally supported, are "POSIX EREs".  See [What flavor of regex does git use](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39789921/1256452) for some additional detail.  However, `git grep` has flags to choose different pattern types, plus `grep.patternType`, while `-L` function name arguments are passed in to `parse_range_funcname` in [line-range.c](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/line-range.c).  Annoyingly, this doesn't even use EREs, but rather BREs, due to [this line](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9d530dc0024503ab4218fe6c4395b8a0aa245478/line-range.c#L209):

```
reg_error = regcomp(&regexp, pattern, REG_NEWLINE);
```

This means that for `-L` expressions in `git log`, not even alternation is allowed.  (`git grep` of course can do alternation.)  This shoots down the idea suggested by [The fourth bird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69705205/how-to-make-a-positive-lookahead-regex-match-when-using-gits-built-in-regex-mat/69712398#comment123209814_69705205).  It might be nice if the function pattern matcher allowed EREs.