# GIT diff ignore "// Generated on: ..."

Tags: regex, git

how should I return names of the changed files ignoring those where the only change is this java comment "// Generated on: ..."

I was triing something like this  `git diff HEAD~1 -G '^(?!\/\/ Generated on.*$).*' --name-only`, but it is complaining `fatal: invalid regex: Invalid preceding regular expression`.

Basically I am quite new to regex so could someone help me to correct the regex expression?

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/39790343/3216427, Git uses POSIX extended regular expressions, which don't support the `(?...)` syntax you're trying to use. I'm not sure "does not contain string X" can be expressed with POSIX EREs, to be honest.

Comment: I was able to achieve if with `^([^\/]|\/($|[^\/]|\/($|[^ ]| ($|[^G]|G($|[^e]|e($|[^n]|n($|[^e]|e($|[^r]|r($|[^a]|a($|[^t]|t($[^e]|e($[^d]|d($[^ ]| ($[^o]|o($|[^n]|n($[^:])))))))))))))))).*` but I would not like to do it again :D. I hope there is better solution.

Comment: Wow, that is horrendous, but good for you for getting that RE written correctly!

Answer (score 0):

Try `git diff HEAD~1 -I'^\/\/ Generated on'`, which ignores the entire line whenever it starts with that string. The `-I` flag enables somewhat simpler regex.

from the docs about [Git-diff](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt--Iltregexgt):

```
-I<regex>
--ignore-matching-lines=<regex>

    Ignore changes whose all lines match <regex>. This
    option may be specified more than once.
```

Comment: Can't just contain, it's looking for a full-line match, add `.*` (or a more precise matcher) to the end.

Comment: I am getting error (bad revision '^\/\/ Generated on') when running this

Comment: Ok, It seems I am on old version of git where -I option is not working yet and unfortunately I can not update.