# Is there a way to print each item in a pattern created with re.compile?

Tags: python, regex, typeerror

I'd like to be able to double check that I have compiled my pattern properly by printing each element after compiling.

I tried this:

```
import re
regex = re.compile('[A-z]')
for l in regex:   # this line raises the TypeError
    print(l)
```

But naturally I get following error:

> TypeError: 're.Pattern' object is not iterable

Is there a way to print following letters?

```
A
B
C
```

Comment: Nope there isn't, you will have to use external packages or come up with something yourself.

Comment: there are sites such as [this](https://www.regexpal.com/) where you can test your regex patterns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To elaborate [Marco Bonelli's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73874490/is-there-a-way-to-print-each-item-in-a-pattern-created-with-re-compile#comment130443322_73874490):

### Short answer: No

There is no programmatic way in Python to represent the compiled pattern like a character-range `[A-C]` in its expanded form, e.g. as a character-set like `[ABC]` or as its elements `'A', 'B', 'C'`.

#### When patterns are interpreted and evaluated

The given pattern is a (regular) expression (regex).
In most regex-engines the regex string is compiled to a pattern-object. When applying this to a string we *match* it. During matching the regex is interpreted by the language, like here Python's [`re` module's source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/dc0a87d9a0cf18fdfc51865a3c1bd2d5ebe9eae9/Lib/re.py).

#### More on regex elements

[Character-classes or -sets](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) like `[A-Z]` are evaluated first during matching against a given string.

Note:

- The notation of most regular-expression elements follows a common interpretation standard. So `[A-Z]` will be interpreted by almost any regex-engine as character-set containing all uppercase letters of the Latin alphabet.
- Some regex elements are specific to certain regex-engines, we call this flavor

See also:

- Wikipedia: Regular Expression, [Character classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_classes)
- [In the regex world what's a flavor and which flavor does Java use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226325/in-the-regex-world-whats-a-flavor-and-which-flavor-does-java-use)